# Android 14 flag mutable

Tags: immutability, android-pendingintent, android-14, android-sharesheet

I'm working to support android 14 in a certain app, i'm having one issue with android native share sheet, since we have a pending intent with FLAG_MUTABLE, i'm getting this error

`2023-10-16 14:23:20.368 10001-10001        com.package.x.android.shopping    E  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.x.android.shop/com.package.x.NativeShareActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.package.x.android.shop: Targeting U+ (version 34 and above) disallows creating or retrieving a PendingIntent with FLAG_MUTABLE, an implicit Intent within and without FLAG_NO_CREATE and FLAG_ALLOW_UNSAFE_IMPLICIT_INTENT for security reasons. To retrieve an already existing PendingIntent, use FLAG_NO_CREATE, however, to create a new PendingIntent with an implicit Intent use FLAG_IMMUTABLE.`

Based on [android 14 documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14), it's not possible anymore to use flag_mutable pendingIntent for security reasons, and changing the pending intent to FLAG_IMMUTABLE will prevent us from getting the shared channel choosed by customer, is there a way to use flag*_immutable and still be able to get the share channel choosed by customer.

I have tried to change the intent type to explicit, however i'm not sure what should be the component name in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Pleas edit your question and show the relevant code. I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can still use the FLAG_MUTABLE with both explicit and implicit intents: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77691101/4726718

Answer (score 1):

The component name is given in the error message:

```
com.package.x.android.shop/com.package.x.NativeShareActivity
```

To make the `Intent` explicit, you should only need to set the package name to `com.package.x.android.shop`.